# Prove that using a range operator in a loop does not use additional memory

Tags: perl, loops

The current documentation for the [Range operator `..`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) states that it will not burn up memory for [counting loops](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=743655):

> ... The range operator is useful for writing `foreach (1..10)` loops and for doing slice operations on arrays. **In the current implementation, no temporary array is created** when the range operator is used as the expression in foreach loops, but older versions of Perl might burn a lot of memory when you write something like this:
>
> ```
>     1.   for (1 .. 1_000_000) {
>     2.       # code
>     3.   }
> ```

Because of the aforementioned early implementations of `for (MIN .. MAX)`, I still come by experts who are wary of using counting loops because they believe it is equivalent to:

```
my @temp_array = (MIN .. MAX);       # Needlessly using up memory
for (@temp_array) {
```

Versus the more logical and memory efficient:

```
for ($_ = MIN; $_ <= MAX; $_++) {    # Logical counting from MIN to MAX
```

Questions:

- Is there a way that one could go about proving that a counting loop does not waste memory?
- Does anyone know which versions of Perl had the memory issue and when it was fixed?

I'm able to prove to myself that counting loops don't waste memory using the below one-liner which would certainly crash my system if it was actually creating a temporary array.  However, it would be nice if there was more conclusive information on the subject so that we could put this old-wives tale to rest.

```
$ perl -e 'for (1 .. 1_000_000_000_000_000) { print "$_\n"; last if $_ == 5 }'
1
2
3
4
5
```

---

#### Solution

Each of the three below answers go part of the way to explaining this issue:

1. [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25214988/1733163) thoroughly breaks down different types loops and demonstrates how counting loops differ on the front and back end.  ☆
2. [friedo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20745/friedo)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25214811/1733163) shows how to use `top` to monitor memory usage.
3. [Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25221144/1733163) addresses the second part of my query about when this no longer became an issue:

   - [`perlop v5.4_68`](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/GSAR/perl5.004_68/pod/perlop.pod#Range-Operators) (released on 23 June 1998) warns a temporary array is used.
   - [`perlop v5.4_69`](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/GSAR/perl5.004_69/pod/perlop.pod#Range-Operators) (released on 29 June 1998) states a temporary array is no longer used.
   - [`perldelta v5.4_71`](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/GSAR/perl5.004_71/pod/perldelta.pod#foreach-1..1000000-optimized) (released on 9 July 1998) states that counting loops are optimized.

I might do some specific version testing at some point, but given this is apparently a 16 year old issue, I'm confident that the warning in `perlop` can be put to rest.

Comment: Also mentioned in [perldelta 5.5](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5005delta.html#foreach-(1..1000000)-optimized)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, here's a list of different types of `for` loops and the optimizations that can be applied. All of these are present in every version of Perl from 5.6 to 5.20 (present) inclusive, and I believe it's comprehensive.

- `for (EXPR; EXPR; EXPR)`
  ⇒ "C-style for loop", an augmented while loop.
- `for (EXPRX..EXPRY)`
  ⇒ A range and nothing else is optimized into a counting loop.
- `for (@ARRAY)`
  ⇒ An array and nothing else is accessed directly rather than being flattened.
- `for (reverse LIST)`
  ⇒ None of the above optimizations apply, but the list is traversed in reverse rather than being reversed.
- `for (LIST)`
  ⇒ In a generic foreach loop, the `LIST` expression is evaluated before the loop starts.

When `CONSTX..CONSTY` is flattened (i.e. anywhere other than in `for (CONSTX..CONSTY)`), it is flattened at compile-time rather than run-time.

---

### Black box proof

Baseline memory usage:

```
$ perl -e'system(ps, ho, rss, 0+$$);'
 1540         # 1.5 MiB
```

The general case flattens.

```
$ perl -e'$y=2_000_000; for ((),1..$y) { system(ps, ho, rss, 0+$$); last }'
80208         # 78 MiB
```

Or worse. (It flattens into an array at compile-time in addition to the normal stack usage.)

```
$ perl -e'for ((),1..2_000_000) { system(ps, ho, rss, 0+$$); last }'
143224        # 140 MiB
```

`for (CONST..CONST)` doesn't flatten.

```
$ perl -e'for (1..2_000_000) { system(ps, ho, rss, 0+$$); last }'
 1540         # 1.5 MiB
```

In fact, `for (EXPR..EXPR)`  in general doesn't flatten.

```
$ perl -e'$y=2_000_000; for (1..$y) { system(ps, ho, rss, 0+$$); last }'
 1540         # 1.5 MiB
```

Even without tools, you could tell the the difference in compilation time.

```
$ time perl -c -e'1 for 1..2_000_000'
-e syntax OK

real    0m0.010s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.000s

$ time perl -c -e'1 for (),1..2_000_000'
-e syntax OK

real    0m1.197s
user    0m0.952s
sys     0m0.232s
```

---

### White box proof

The unoptimized case uses a range operator in **l**ist context. Full list in memory.

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'$y=1_000_000; 1 for (),1..$y;'
...
8  <|> range(other->9)[t3] lK/1                      <-- Range operator
9      <#> gvsv[*y] s
a      <1> flop lKM
           goto b
i  <$> const[IV 1] s
j  <1> flip[t4] lK/LINENUM
b  <#> gv[*_] s
c  <{> enteriter(next->d last->g redo->d) lK/8       <-- No S
...
```

This is what a range flattened at compile-time looks like:

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'1 for (),1..1_000_000;'
...
4  <$> const[AV ] s                                  <-- Constant array
5  <1> rv2av lKPM/1
6  <#> gv[*_] s
7  <{> enteriter(next->8 last->b redo->8) lK/8       <-- No S
...
```

You can see that `for (CONST..CONST)` creates an `enteriter` with the "S" flag. On `enteriter`, the "S" flag means it's a counting loop.

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'1 for 1..1_000_000;'
...
4  <$> const[IV 1] s
5  <$> const[IV 1000000] s
6  <#> gv[*_] s
7  <{> enteriter(next->8 last->b redo->8) lKS/8       <-- S
...
```

Same for `for (EXPR..EXPR)` in general.

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'$y=1_000_000; 1 for 1..$y;'
...
8  <$> const[IV 1] s
9  <#> gvsv[*y] s
a  <#> gv[*_] s
b  <{> enteriter(next->c last->f redo->c) lKS/8       <-- S
...
```

Even `for (@a)` isn't flattened!

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'1 for @a;'
...
4  <#> gv[*a] s
5  <1> rv2av[t2] sKRM/1
6  <#> gv[*_] s
7  <{> enteriter(next->8 last->b redo->8) lKS/8       <-- S
...
```

Double-check

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'1 for (),@a;'
...
4  <#> gv[*a] s
5  <1> rv2av[t2] lKM/1
6  <#> gv[*_] s
7  <{> enteriter(next->8 last->b redo->8) lK/8        <-- No S
...
```

Looking up the code for the "S" flag will confirm all of this.

- [`pp_enteriter`](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/d7d4eceb184d8fc54797d661a6d5ff9a4a7048c3:/pp_ctl.c#l2094) (`PL_op->op_flags & OPf_STACKED` checks for "S")
- [`pp_iter`](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/d7d4eceb184d8fc54797d661a6d5ff9a4a7048c3:/pp_hot.c#l1821).

Comment: I haven't learned [`B::Concise`](http://perldoc.perl.org/B/Concise.html) yet, so I was hoping you or someone would be able to decipher its output.  Is there a resource that you'd recommend for learning it?  the docs seem quite confusing.  Also, for different types of for loops, is it worth mentioning `for (reverse EXPRX..EXPRY)` ?

Comment: It's covered by `for (reverse LIST)`.

Comment: The useful bits are usually the name of the op, its args (e.g. `*a` in `gv[*a]`) and its context (`s`/`l`/`v`, or none of those if its the last expression of a sub). *I* don't even know what the rest means except for the first column, which are alpha-numeric line numbers. The meaning of `S` is op-specific.

Comment: If you don't use `-exec`, you'll see some `ex-` ops with `-` for "line" number. Those were optimized away. Without `-exec`, each line ends with `->X` indicating which op to execute next.

Comment: What is your meaning behind "Black Box" and "White Box"? (calling it a night for now, thanks)

Comment: The terms are often used with reference to testing. One has no knowledge of the internals of a [black box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_box_%28systems%29). (Examples of black box testing include clicking on everything, trying weird inputs, etc.) A [white box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_box_%28software_engineering%29) is the opposite. (Examples of white box testing include making sure every branch is taken, etc.) In the Black Box section of my answer, I examine the box as a whole. In the White Box section, I dove into it (the code that was generated and Perl's source code).

Comment: +1 for suggesting the form `(),1..1_000_000` to force the Perl interpreter into old habits

Comment: @Borodin, The black box part is accessible, but the OP wanted to look into Perl's guts, and there's no way that can be commonly digestable. I spent more than two hours on that post as it is.

Comment: @ikegami Thank you for this thorough explanation.  I duplicated and confirmed each step of your study myself.  Going to be a while before I get truly understand `B::Concise`, but this is a very useful example to start with.

Answer (score 4):

**Is there a way that one could go about proving that a counting loop does not waste memory?**

One way might be to monitor the process with `top`. For example:

```
perl -E 'for( 1 .. 1_000_000_000_000 ) { say $_ }' > /tmp/blah & top -pid $!
```

This shows that the memory usage remains fairly constant (and trivial) while the program runs, despite iterating a list of one trillion items.

**Does anyone know which versions of Perl had the memory issue and when it was fixed?**

I couldn't find the precise version when this was changed with a quick grep of the perldeltas. I will note that `perlop` mentions it:

```
The range operator is useful for writing "foreach (1..10)" loops and for doing
slice operations on arrays. In the current implementation, no temporary
array is created when the range operator is used as the expression in
"foreach" loops, but older versions of Perl might burn a lot of memory
when you write something like this:

    for (1 .. 1_000_000) {
        # code
    }
```

But it doesn't say when that optimization was introduced. In any case, it was a long time ago.

Comment: Yes, those were the docs I quoted to lead off my question.  I totally agree that an analysis of `top` should be sufficient proof.  However, I still come by fellow experts who are wary of using it, so was hoping for additional evidence.  If I can learn `Concise`, then ikegami's post might have the information to finally put this issue to rest.  Thanks.

Comment: @Miller, Honestly, that's backwards. Actually examining memory usage is a far more accurate way of determining memory usage than studying the interpreter.

Answer (score 3):

The last time `perlop` says this

> Be aware that under the current implementation, a temporary array is created, so you'll burn a lot of memory if you write something like this:

is in version `5.4_68`.

In `5.4_69` (released on 29 June 1998) it changes to being very close to the current version

> In the current implementation, no temporary array is created when the range operator is used as the
>   expression in C loops, but older versions of Perl might burn a lot of memory when you write something like this:

But I can't find the change mentioned in a `perldelta` anywhere!

Anyway, we're talking about a sixteen-year-old fix,

Comment: Wow, that was a long time ago.  This subject came up in an interview recently, but I had trouble persuading them it was no longer an issue.  The fact that I was recovering from a 102 temp might have played a role with my inability to form a convincing argument though :)

Comment: @Miller: I had to roll back your amendment. You should post your own solution regarding the `perldelta` entry

Comment: I was considering creating a script based off ikegami's information and testing a bunch of perlbrews, but based off the info you found that seems a waste of effort.  I wouldn't have found the link to the perldelta if you hadn't found the versions with the change to perlop, so it feels appropriate to just roll into your post.

Comment: @Miller: Thank you, but I think it serves better if your insight is presented as additional information. We are also missing some information about which versions were made public back then. I am sure it is before the *Star Trek* convention that only alternate versions are worthy of release. I am also considering publishing my own notes about what major changes happened in which distribution, as the perldeltas contain only the orthogonal version, which is just a convenience for perl5.porters

Comment: Yes, I noticed a trend that some of those perldeltas repeated themselves, so obviously they were intended as a work in progress before a major release.  Listing the first reference seemed a reasonable compromise though since the update to perlop occurred before it.

Comment: @Miller: Maybe. I think it may simply have been in the days when there was little distinction between the development version and what was in the field. If you look at `perlhist` you can see that the idea of *betas* only started when the numbering system changed with 5.5.650. I'm sure a message to `perl.perl5.porters` would get you the answers, although you may well have to deal with the odd few who would like you to think they have the answer but in fact are more interested in self-promotion

Comment: Re "Anyway, we're talking about a sixteen-year-old fix," Aye, I mentioned it's been the current way since at least 5.6, and that came out in 2000. Re "I was considering creating a script based off ikegami's information and testing a bunch of perlbrews", Cool! I didn't know perlbrew actually support versions that old.